# Is $\log u\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ if $u\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)~~u>0$??

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I trying to show that if  $u\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)~~u>0$ then $\log u\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$.

My attempt

Let $D\subset\subset\Omega$ and $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(D)$
$$\int_{D}\frac{\partial \log u}{\partial x_i}\varphi dx=\int_{D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{1}{u}\varphi dx=\int_{D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\varphi}{u} dx~~(1)$$

Since $u\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ then $\exists~~g_1\ldots g_n\in L^{p}(D)$ such that $\forall \varphi\in C^\infty_0(D)$
$$\int_{D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\varphi dx=-\int_{D}g_i\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i}dx$$

In (1) this yields

$$\int_{D}\frac{\partial \log u}{\partial x_i}\varphi dx=-\int_{D}g_i\frac{\partial \frac{\varphi}{u}}{\partial x_i}dx$$

i got stuck here, any remark or hint would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $u>0$. You can only mean $u>0$ a.e. I guess, because we are talking about $L^p_{loc}$-functions. And please specify $\Omega$. Is it bounded, open, closed?

Comment: $\Omega$ is open connected set in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: $u \in L^{p}$ doesn't imply $\log(|u|) \in L^{p}$ to start with.  $u(x) = \exp(-x^{-1}) \in L^{\infty}([0,1])$, but $\log(u(x)) = - x^{-1} \notin L^{p}([0,1])$ no matter which $p \in [0,\infty]$ you take.

Comment: @PeterMorfe thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is untrue. Consider $\Omega = (-1, 1)$ and $u(x) := \lvert x \rvert$. Clearly $u>0$ (in an a.e. sense) and $u \in L^1(\Omega)$. Since $u'(x) = \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert}$ a.e. in a weak sense (this is can easily be computed using integration by parts), we have, because of $\log\circ u$ being $C^1$ in $\Omega \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, that $\log(u(x))' = \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert^2}$ is the only possible candidate for the weak derivative. But $\log(u(x))'$ does not live in $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$:
$$
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2} \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{\lvert x \rvert^2}~\mathrm{d}x = 2 \int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{x}~\mathrm{d}x = 4 - 2\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \log(x) = \infty
$$

Quick sidenote: If $u>0$ and $u \in W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ and $f \in C^1([0, \infty))$ with $f'$ bounded, then $f(u) \in W^{1, p}(\Omega)$. About the $loc$ case I am not quite sure.

Comment: I see that the problem came from that $u>0$ a.e. what if $u>0$ every where..?

Comment: Kind of, yep. But you could also choose $u(x) := \lvert x \rvert$ if $x \neq 0$ and $u(0) := 1$, then the same problem arises, which is, that the derivative explodes near $0$. But there is no such thing as $u \in W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ and $u>0$ EVERYWHERE. You should look up the equivalence class definition of $L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Meodog Im note sure why the function u that you choose is in $W^{1,1}(-1,1)$ loc

Comment: Just look up "absolute value in sobolev space", you can find it all over the internet. It's a generic problem. $u$ is acutally in every sobolev space $W^{1,p}((-1,1))$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$.

Comment: ah yes i see why $u>0$ can only be understood in a.e sense, we work with a class of functions.

Comment: Exactly this is it

Comment: thank you for your time

Comment: So whats the meanning of the $\nabla\log (u)$ in this corollary ??
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uGFSei4Bp4AkkzXI9IJX09gaV34gyB9I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would have to take some time for this, but $u$ bring continuous should do the Trick here for weak differentiability. Also depends on $G$...

Comment: here is the original article 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fABO6Aplg8q2lQX49SONIEL-IqBQTGV4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay this is probably because of $u$ being superharmonic, nur I cannot quite figure out a rigorous reasoning

Comment: thank you very much